# PHP list directories and remove .. and 

Tags: php

I created a script that list the directories in the current directory

```
<?php
   $dir = getcwd(); 
   if($handle = opendir($dir)){
       while($file = readdir($handle)){
          if(is_dir($file)){
             echo "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a><br />";
            }
       }
?>
```

but the problem is, I am seeing this ".." and "." right above the directory listings, when someone clicks it, they get redirected one level up the directories.. can someone tell me how to remove those ".." and "." ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use opendir/readdir/closedir functions, you have to check manually:

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
      if ($file === '.' || $file === '..' || !is_dir($file)) continue;
      echo "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a><br />";
    }
}
?>
```

If you want to use *DirectoryIterator*, there is isDot() method:

```
<?php
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
foreach ($iterator as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isDir()) continue;
    $file = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    echo "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a><br />";
}
?>
```

Note: I think that continue can simplify this kind of loops by reducing indentation level.

Answer (score 3):

Or use [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

```
foreach(glob('/path/*.*') as $file) {
    printf('<a href="%s">%s</a><br/>', $file, $file);
}
```

If your files don't follow the *filename dot extension* pattern, use

```
array_filter(glob('/path/*'), 'is_file')
```

to get an array of (non-hidden) filenames only.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   if($handle = opendir($dir)){
       while($file = readdir($handle)){
          if(is_dir($file) && $file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
             echo "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a><br />";
            }
       }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Skips all hidden and "dot directories":

```
while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if (substr($file, 0, 1) == '.') {
        continue;
    }
```

Skips dot directories:

```
while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
```