# readdir() reads nonexistent files "." and ".."

Tags: php, file

I'm a basic php programmer, with a simple website with users and profile pictures.

There is a folder called `ppic` (profile pictures).

When I use `readdir()` like it says on the [php.net site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), it prints out two nonexistent files.

If I put a `echo "there was a match - $entry<br>;` inside the `while` loop with `$entry` being the file name, it prints out:

```
there was a match - .
there was a match - ..
there was a match - Autumn Leaves.jpg
there was a match - Creek.jpg
there was a match - Toco Toucan.jpg
```

I only have three files in the folder: "Autumn Leaves.jpg", "Creek.jpg", and "Toco Toucan.jpg".

I'm not too great with computers, so I have no idea what those dots mean.

Can somebody please explain these to me?

Comment: Unix operating systems maintain a directory `.` for the current directory, and `..` for the parent directory.

Comment: Single dot "." stands for current directory and double dots ".." mean parent directory. This really doesn't have anything to do with PHP and is more of a Linux file system question.

Comment: Why do they show up as files then? Directories aren't files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP list directories and remove .. and](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416137/php-list-directories-and-remove-and) or [Exclude Hidden Files from Scandir PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8532569)

Comment: Every directory shows up as file. In fact it historically was a file, with as binary contents a file listing, and `..` a link.

Comment: Related: [Why do directory listings contain the current (.) and parent (..) directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/322719/1438393)

Comment: Note how the documentation's example takes this into account with `if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Learn UNIX basics: (and other common filesystem handlings)

The `.` is a virtual symbolic link to the current folder (e.g. `./Creek.jpg` is, resolved, the same as `Creek.jpg`)

The `..` is a virtual symbolic link to the parent folder.

To hide them, just manually exclude then via `$file !== '.' && $file !== '..'`.

Comment: [Not only Unix-like; Windows and others use them as well.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_\(computing\))

Comment: @Gumbo: I wrote Unix, not Linux……… (and mean the unixoid systems…)